# Replace Fakepath with php

Tags: php

I am uploading an image via AJAX and the image uploads ok but the image´s name  I am saving on database is like this:

c:\fakepath\2_3.png

How can I get rid of this "c:\fakepath\" before the image´s name with PHP.

Thanks

Comment: is "fakepath" your root directory?

Comment: based on the answers below which appear to be valid but you state are not working, I think it would be helpful for you to provide some code related to how you're creating the value that is going into your database.

Comment: No fakepath is the string that explorer and and chrome adds to the image for some security reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The back slash is tripping basename up.

Here is the solution:

```
<?
$file = 'c:\fakepath\blah.jpg';
echo basename( $file ) . "<br>";

$file = str_replace( "\\", '/', $file );

echo basename( $file ) . "<br>";
```

**output:**

```
c:\fakepath\blah.jpg
blah.jpg
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$filename = basename("c:\fakepath\2_3.png");
echo $filename; //2_3.png
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct one which I have tried and tested. And it works!!

```
<?php
$file = 'c:\fakepath\blah.jpg';
$file = str_replace( "c:\fakepath\", '', $file );
echo $file;
?>
```